# Angular2 Custom Component - mark as pristine and untouched

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a template driven form in Angular 2.1 containing many standard controls (`<input>, <select>` etc) and a custom control which itself contains multiple input elements.

I've implemented ControlValueAccessor on the custom control and it is propagating it's changed/touched/valid values correctly to the parent form.

However .. on the parent form I have a Save button, on which after saving I want to clear the dirty/touched state (as this affects the css applied) like this:

```
save(myForm: NgForm) {

    myForm.form.markAsPristine();
    myForm.form.markAsUntouched();

}
```

This is working ok for all the elements in the top level parent form and the custom control itself **but** the `<input>` fields within the custom control are still marked as touched/dirty (and this receiving the pre-saved styling).

Is there a way that the custom control can be notified when it's dirty/touched state is changed so that it can then clear it's child `<input>` elements to match? It seems that if the `<input>` elements are within a custom control they don't get updated by calls to markAsPristine/Untouched on the parent Form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to add `controls['nameOfControl']` like this

```
 myForm.form.controls['nameOfControl'].markAsPristine();
```

The code above will only work for form controls.

THe following seems to be a good work around:

```
  active = true;
  newModel() {
    this.model = new yourModel(2, '',true, '');
    this.active = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.active = true, 0);
  }
```

Reset the form with a new Model AND to restore the 'pristine' class state.
by toggling the 'active' flag will cause the form to be removed/re-added in a tick via NgIf.  Yes it is a small work around until they can can fix :)

hope that helps

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work .. that only marks the custom component with 'nameOfContrlol' as pristine .. not an input elements within that control

Comment: Yep, I had seen that workaround described in the previous version of the doco (and on SO) for resetting the form's values ... was hoping to avoid that just to hook into dirty/touched properties .. but might give it a shot

Comment: FormBuilders, FormControls, and FormGroups do offer offer those features out of the box if you end up in a hacky dead end.

Comment: if you have a such a big form you can do like this
this.form.reset()
this.form.markAsPristine()

Answer (score 21):

The workaround with the active flag does the job but I also found another way.

On the parent form, I can access my custom child component as ViewChild.

i.e in the parent form:

```
@ViewChild(CustomChildComponent) child1: CustomChildComponent;
```

Then when I save in the parent form, call that child directly.

```
save(myForm: NgForm) {

   // clear anything at the parent form level
   myForm.form.markAsPristine();
   myForm.form.markAsUntouched();

   // tell the custom component to do the same
   this.child1.markAsPristineAndUntouched();
}
```

Where in CustomChildComponent I've defined
..

```
// get the input controls in the the child that we want to clear 
@ViewChild('surname') surnameField: NgModel;

markAsPristineAndUntouched() { 

   this.surnameField.control.markAsPristine();
   this.surnameField.control.markAsUntouched();
   // .. clear other controls .. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wasted so much time on this and was so simple at the end!

Answer (score 4):

[`markAsPristine()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsPristine) can affect the control itself, and possibly **all its direct ancestor** controls (i.e. parents, grandparents, great grandparents)

`markAsPristine()` takes an `opts` argument;
`markAsPristine(opts: { onlySelf?: boolean; } = {})`. When the `onlySelf` value is *false* (which is the default value )), the control and all its direct ancestors are marked as pristine. If `onlySelf` is *true*; only the control itself is marked as pristine.

In my case, I wanted to mark all **descendant** controls  (i.e. child, grandchild, etc) as pristine/untouched. **I can do this using [`FormGroup.reset()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset)** ; [`reset()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) has the ability to affect **descendants**:

> Resets the FormGroup, marks **all descendants are marked pristine and untouched**, and the value of all descendants to null.

So with the OP's code I could reset the form, using the values it already has:

```
myForm.form.reset(myForm.form.getRawValue(), {emitEvent: false})
```

Note how I avoid certain side effects:

- I use the form's **current values**, so I *don't change current values*.
- I **use [`getRawValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)**, instead of `value`, to *get the value of disabled controls*.
- I **don't `emitEvent`**; which means *no valueChanges will be triggered*.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to observe the host changes.

I have a component implementing the controlValueAccesor interface. I use this component into a form, with ngModel.

When Angular forms api changes the host element class attribute setting it to dirty, prinstine, touched, etc... I set mi component class attibute to the host class attribute.

constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {

```
this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
  mutations.forEach(
    (mutation: MutationRecord) => (this.controlClasses = mutation.target['className']),
  );
});

this.changes.observe(this.hostElement.nativeElement, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
});
```

}

On template

```
 <span class="ui-float-label">
  <input
    #inputElement
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [type]="type"
    [required]="required"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="handleValueChange($event)"
    (blur)="onBlur()"
    [pattern]="pattern"
    [type]="type"
    [size]="size"
    pInputText
    class="p-inputtext"
    [ngClass]="controlClasses"
  />

  <label *ngIf="!required" for="float-input">{{ placeholder }}</label>
  <label *ngIf="required" for="float-input">{{ placeholder }}*</label>
</span>
```

Now each time the host change his classes the change is propagated to the child control.